# Why Ajax get 500 internal error on laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

I have function select2 and using ajax . but this get 500 internal error 
can someone tell where this wrong this code ?

```
<script>

$('#inventaris').on('change',function(e){
    console.log(e);
    $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
    });
    var alat_id = e.target.value;

    //ajax
    $.get('/admin-sarpras/get_status?alat_id='+ alat_id, function(data){
      //success data
      console.log(data);
    });

});
```

and this my controller and my route

```
 Route::get('get_status', 'AdminController@get_status')->name('get_status');
```

this controller

```
public function get_status(Request $request)
{
    $alat_id = $request->alat_id;

    $status_alat = Alat::where('id' , $alat_id)->get();

    return Response::json($status_alat);

}
```

this is showing on **network**

> http://localhost:8000/admin-sarpras/get_status?alat_id=10

someone can correct where i am wrong ?

Comment: The first place to look should be your server log (usually `/var/log/apache2/error.log` or similar, and the body of the response in your browser's Developer Tools.

Comment: You can debug in my putting log of each line so that you will get better idea from which line you get this error

Comment: i add debugger , but i still dont know

Comment: error 500 is not from your code and it says that server has some problems! check or restart your server

Comment: i am sorry , this is solved . i forgot to add use respones . case closed

Comment: @AdhikMulat If your problem is solved, please consider answering your own question with the solution. This might help others facing the same issue.